# plan to versus plan that

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence correct

They  **planned that** they would read this book but they did not.

or is it better to say

They **planned to** read this book but they did not .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of saying this is "planned to read". The *to* belongs to the infinitive verb *to read*.